# ¿Cómo crear una lista de usuarios y grupos a los que pertenecen en el directorio?

Tags: get, powershell, activedirectory

Estoy intentando extraer los grupos de mi AD y sus usuarios para poder tratarlos individualmente en un script de python pero **necesito que aparezca un entrada por cada grupo**, es decir:

| Usuario | Grupo |
| --- | --- |
| Santiago | 1 |
| Santiago | 2 |
| Santiago | 3 |

**Actualmente tengo** la siguiente salida:

| Usuario | Grupo |
| --- | --- |
| Santiago | 1,2,3 |

Este es el código de PowerShell que tengo:

```
    $Report = @()
#-Properties extrae los atributos requeridos del usuario (mirar en lab)
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, GivenName, sn, mail, SurName, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, MemberOf, Enabled -ResultSetSize $Null
#En cada loop extrae atributos de ese usuario


Foreach($User in $users){
$UserGroupCollection = $User.MemberOf

#Array para las pertenencias a grupo

$UserGroupMembership = @()

Foreach($UserGroup in $UserGroupCollection){
$GroupDetails = Get-ADGroup -Identity $UserGroup

$UserGroupMembership += $GroupDetails.Name
}

$Groups = $UserGroupMembership -join ‘, ‘
#Definimos los atributos que aparecen en el csv final (revisar)

$Out = New-Object PSObject
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Nombre -Value $User.GivenName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Apellido -Value $User.sn
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UPN -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name mail -Value $User.mail
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UserName -Value $User.SamAccountName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Status -Value $User.Enabled
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Groups -Value $Groups
$Report += $Out
}

$Report | Sort-Object Name | FT -AutoSize
$Report | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path ‘C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\EXT\datos1.CSV’ -NoTypeInformation
```

¿Cómo podría sacarlo interviniendo directamente en el csv o en la consulta de powerShell o en python?

Por favor y muchas gracias.
Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Se puede si haces un ciclo for con la variable $UserGroupMembership, incluyendo los datos que se añadan dentro de ese for y por cada grupo, para que no sea tan confuso colocare el código completo.

```
$Report = @()
#-Properties extrae los atributos requeridos del usuario (mirar en lab)
$Users = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Name, GivenName, sn, mail, SurName, SamAccountName, UserPrincipalName, MemberOf, Enabled -ResultSetSize $Null
#En cada loop extrae atributos de ese usuario


Foreach($User in $users){
$UserGroupCollection = $User.MemberOf

#Array para las pertenencias a grupo

$UserGroupMembership = @()

Foreach($UserGroup in $UserGroupCollection){
$GroupDetails = Get-ADGroup -Identity $UserGroup

$UserGroupMembership += $GroupDetails.Name
}

Foreach($Grupo in $UserGroupMembership){
    
$Out = New-Object PSObject
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Nombre -Value $User.GivenName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Apellido -Value $User.sn
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UPN -Value $User.UserPrincipalName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name mail -Value $User.mail
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name UserName -Value $User.SamAccountName
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Status -Value $User.Enabled
$Out | Add-Member -MemberType noteproperty -Name Groups -Value $Grupo
$Report += $Out
}

}

$Report | Sort-Object Name | FT -AutoSize
$Report | Sort-Object Name | Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8 -Path ‘C:\Users\Administrador\Desktop\EXT\datos1.CSV’ -NoTypeInformation
```

Espero serte de ayuda, a mi usando una ruta que existe en mi PC me funciona.